# AWS - Glue , Dev End point two Small node v/s one large node

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Just wanted to understand about the Dev End point in AWS GLUE pricing . What will charge more if i use two small Dev Endpoint like 32 Gb / 10 DPU and a large Dev end point with specs like 20 DPU with 64 Gb Ram. 
I wants to understand what will be cheaper option in case we need to submit multiple jobs at same time .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You get charged something like $0.44 per DPU per hour running. So if you start a dev endpoint provisioned with 10 DPUs and play around with it for an hour your bill would be $4.40
Cost can vary by region - https://aws.amazon.com/glue/pricing/

Comment: Make sure you turn the dev endpoints off when you're done, or that you don't let a job run for too long - you can really rack up significant cost quickly with Glue  or anything AWS for that matter.